# Positioning 3 divs absolutely inside a container left, center, right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to center a logo div inside a header that has 3 total divs. The positioning I am going for is left, center, right.

***The problem is that the left and right div will push the center div depending on the length of the content on either side.***

I want the center div to not be affected by the left and right divs.

Here is my code example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KDhou

```
<header>
 <div class="left">LEFT ALSO PUSHES CENTER DIV</div>
 <div class="right"> RIGHT PUSHES CENTER DIV</div>
 <div class="center">CENTER</div>
</header>
```

and the css

```
 header{
 color:white; 
   position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #2995f3;}

.center{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background:green;
}
.left{
    float: left;
    background:grey
}
.right{
    float: right;
    background:red
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the right and left divs a max width to go to?

Comment: I don't want to restrain the left and right divs to fixed widths because it is a responsive layout

Comment: position:absolute REMOVES the element from it's containing element. You want position:relative for the .center div. Give the left and right divs a width, then assign your values to your center div. Also, in your HTML it should be left -- center -- right

Comment: Is there a way to not adjust the widths...

Comment: without giving the header or left and right elements a specified width, you're pretty much screwed. You're going to have to give something an actual width so that the css has something to base off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here-> http://jsfiddle.net/KLXPL/1/. Your center div remains in the center when the browser size is changed. This is the `HTML` and `CSS` I used:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="left">LEFT ALSO PUSHES CENTER DIV</div>
    <div class="right">RIGHT PUSHES CENTER DIV</div>
    <div class="center">CENTER</div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    color:white;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #2995f3;
}
.center {
    clear:both;
    display: inline-block;
    background:green;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background:grey;
    display:inline-block;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: He doesn't want to give widths to the elements, otherwise it would be as simple as you state.

Comment: Edited my answer. No fixed width attached to the elements anymore. The center div still remains in the center.

Comment: Is it possible to fixed position an element inside a container? so that it is centered inside that container regardless of other elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, your new code isn't actually centered, because if you add or remove content from either left or right it pushes the center again.

Comment: well, there's a way to do it with a table... but you wont like it

Comment: @AntonB Yes, ofcourse AntonB. That's why I had initially provided a fixed width. If the content changes (increases) then the browser would try to fit in all the content in the 'left' and 'right' divs, thereby leaving no space for the center div. Hence, the `center` div doesn't remain centered.

Comment: @AntonB With fixed width, the 'center' text remains centered irrespective of the content.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend some changes in your .css file.

```
 header{
color:white; 
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
left: 0;
width:100%;
top: 0;
background-color: #2995f3;}

.center{
position: fixed;
display: inline-block;
background:green;
}
.left{
left:0px;
position:fixed;
background:grey
}
.right{
right:0px;
position:fixed;
background:red
}
```

position of .center, .left & also .right classes to fixed
and eliminate floats from .left and .right and add `left:0px;` and `right:0px;` respectively.
Here it is..  http://codepen.io/rjeet0/pen/xyDGg
 .Thank you.

Comment: my problem with this is the header background is no longer visible because it is not stretching the height of the other elements as they are "fixed" any workaround? @user3753346

Comment: You can use width option for you green background. use this width:80px; http://codepen.io/rjeet0/pen/xiJlk

Answer (score 0):

If you set your `.center` class to be styled with:

```
.center{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background:green;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
```

you can make the logo center taking as reference the `header` width.

Comment: This cuts the center off if it stretches a little longer.